# Word adding extra blank space between paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

Microsoft word is interpreting 0 points before or after a paragraph as at least 14-20 points. I can add extra space after the paragraph by adjusting the paragraph parameters but the paragraph itself defaults to this giant gap even at 0pt. There's only one paragraph break, and I feel like I've checked absolutely everything. Am I missing something obvious? Is there some hidden menu somewhere?

There seems to be a solution, but it involves laboriously copying and pasting paragraphs without formatting and then reformatting them, and aside from this being a 100+ page document, there are numerous footnotes, endnotes, and highlighted reviewer comments that need to be maintained, so that's a far less than ideal solution.

Comment: Don't select any of the text of the 2nd paragraph and you will see the issue in the paragraph toolbar panel.

Comment: I don't know why you deleted my answer. It certainly -did- answer the question... Do a shift-return for a single line paragraph break. To make it permanent, go into the Spacing section and set Before and After to 0 pt and Line spacing to Single. You may need to click the little button in the lower right of the paragraph section to get the full menu...

Comment: No, the single paragraph has the same issues as both paragraphs. If they didn't share formatting one of those entries would show a blank instead of a value. Also BobT your answer doesn't address the question. The spacing is ALREADY set to 0pt for both paragraphs.

Comment: But I'll bet the line spacing is not set to 'single' under the paragraph spacing settings...

Comment: The paragraphs are set to single line spacing, as you can see from the fact that they are set that way in the image.

Comment: If you've pasted in these paragraphs,  the you shoul place the cursor in each one, then DOUBLE-CLICK its paragraph style in the Styles selector window.

Comment: If you've pasted in these paragraphs,  the you shoul place the cursor in each one, then DOUBLE-CLICK its paragraph style in the Styles selector window. Don't trust word with pasted-in 'formatted' text. Try pasting the text into a text editor and then copying from there to word and see if your results are now what needed.

Comment: I've actually found the answer is very similar to what you're saying here. The paragraphs have a "hidden" style. The style is set to add 2pt before and 8pt after ad for some reason those values don't show up in the Layout tab. I've corrected a sample pagraph to the 6pt after style that is required and it now shows up on the Layout tab correctly.

Comment: Hidden graphic? Invisible inserted field? Section break inserted accidentally? It is weird that the space is there if Space Before/After are really set to 0 for both paragraphs.

Answer (score -1):

Do a shift-return for a single line paragraph break. To make it permanent, go into the Spacing section and set Before and After to 0 pt and Line spacing to Single. You may need to click the little button in the lower right of the paragraph section to get the full menu...

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: I read the question. I understand that he's already set before and after to 0. There is another parameter called 'Line Spacing' that should be set to 'Single' to get the spacing between paragraphs he seems to want. I don't see that parameter mentioned as having been set.

Comment: I'm not very conversant with the mini-Markdown formatting used here, so perhaps you saw the original post with just a link to the image, but you can definitely see in the image that both paragraphs are single spaced and there is only one <p> character between them, which would eliminate the possibility of a double-spaced paragraph hiding between the two paragraphs shown.